# AJAX reply as array from HTML form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is my situation : When the user clicks on "private members only" option a search option appears . He can select the users 
typing their names and this is done with ajax . Now I want to print the members selected in the form  so that the user can remove
later if he wants before submitting the form . For that I want the id's of the searched members in an array . But
I am doing something wrong , only the last selected member's id appears . Please help me getting the selected members array .

Javascript :

```
http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
        {
            //alert("selected"+id);
            document.getElementById("selected").innerHTML = http.responseText;
            //alert(http.responseText)

        }
    }
    var url = "index.php?menu=selected&ajax=ajax&id="+id;
    http.open("POST",url,true);
    http.send(null);
```

PHP:

```
            $id[] = $_REQUEST['id'];
            $this->printSelectedMembers($id);
            break;

function printSelectedMembers($id = array())
{

    var_dump($id);//returns last selected member's id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're replacing your div content. You should **append** to it. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("selected").innerHTML += http.responseText + ", "; //A comma to separate
```

You can use any separator instead of `,`

Note that we replaced the `+` by the `+=` operator

Hope this helps, cheers